# How to format pandas dataframe into google sheets api properly

Tags: python, json, dataframe, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get some data from python to google sheets through the google sheets API. The data is formatted through a df where amounts_a, shoesize_a and frequency_a are all lists

```
  df_asks = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "Asks(USD)":amounts_a,
                "Shoes Size(US)":shoesize_a,
                "Frequency":frequency_a 
            }
        )
```

[Present dataframe format, printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbk0M.png)

Code used to update the spreadsheet:

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

spreadsheetId = "xxx"
range_ = sheetname + coordinate 
value_input_option = "USER_ENTERED"
value_range_body = {
    "majorDimension":"COLUMNS",
    "values":
        [data]
    }
request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=range_, 
                                                valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
print (request)
response = request.execute()
```

When trying to update the spreadsheet values with the present data format, I receive the following error
"TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable"

I converted the dataframes to json using (.to_json()), which then works but the data format in the spreadsheet is the [entire dataframe in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afKQq.png)

How can I transfer this dataframe into sheets with the proper format (as seen in the printed version)?

I am new to working with dataframes and the api, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the value of `values` property for the method of spreadsheets.values.update in Sheets API is required to be 2 dimensional array.
- From your question, I understood that you might want to put the value of `df_asks` to the Spreadsheet by converting `df_asks` to `data`.

In this answer, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `data` is modified as follows.

From:

```
value_range_body = {
    "majorDimension":"COLUMNS",
    "values":
        [data]
    }
```

To:

```
data = [df_asks.columns.values.tolist()]
data.extend(df_asks.values.tolist())
value_range_body = {"values": data}
```

- When you don't want to include the header row, I think that you can also use `data` as `data = df_asks.values.tolist()`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [Resource: ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)

Comment: @Mete Bulbul Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.